# Assigning value to pointer without new

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

Based on my basic knowledge about C++, I assumed following code will have run-time error. Because compiler has not allocate any space for the `y` pointer, and I should add the `y = new int;` before assigning value to `y` pointer.

Am I wrong or compiler has allocate space for `y` pointer implicitly? (I compiled my code with Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int* x;
    int* y;               
    x = new int;          
    *x = 42;              
    cout << *x << "\n";   
    *y = 13;              
    cout << *y << "\n";   
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. The code is still buggy.

Comment: It certainly did not.

Comment: It might be undefined behaviour which just does not show a bug.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Which part of code?

Comment: The statement `*y = 13;` is writing to uninitialized memory.

Comment: @Codor: But I get result. In output I see 42 & 13.

Comment: @user2910740 This might be the case, but it still the result of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Codor No, there are too many "questions" about trivial bugs on SO already. These have little value. Duplicating them has no value.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.1 states:

> An lvalue (3.10) of a
>   non-function, non-array type T can be
>   converted to an rvalue. If T is an
>   incomplete type, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is
>   ill-formed. If the object to which the
>   lvalue refers is not an object of type
>   T and is not an object of a type
>   derived from T, or **if the object is
>   uninitialized**, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion **has
>   undefined behavior**. If T is a
>   non-class type, the type of the rvalue
>   is the cv-unqualified version of T.
>   Otherwise, the type of the rvalue is
>   T.

Undefined means anything can happen - there is no guarantee.

From Wiki [Making pointers safer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#Making_pointers_safer)

> A pointer which does not have any address assigned to it is called a wild pointer. Any attempt to use such uninitialized pointers can cause unexpected behavior, either because the initial value is not a valid address, or because using it may damage other parts of the program. The result is often a segmentation fault, storage violation or wild branch (if used as a function pointer or branch address).

Answer (score 1):

> Am I wrong or compiler has allocate space for y pointer implicitly?

it has not,and such assignment is Undefined Behaviour. This means it can work and not cause any problems for long time, but suddenly can crash your application. Variable y is actually assigned some random value, and `*y=13;` assignes 13 to some random memory address which can be a valid memory address of some structure or stack. If you would initialize y to nullptr (or 0, NULL) initially `int* y=nullptr;`, then you should have application crash.